# UItableview rows not showing with mapkit in swift4

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, mapkit

I am trying to have a mapkit and a uitable on a viewcontroller. I have the mapkit working with the annoitations, but I would like to show the names on a uitable below the mapkit.

What is happening is that the 'tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath:' does not even get noticed. I tried adding 'self.tableView.reloadData()' but still not.

Can some one let me now where I am going wrong?

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import CoreLocation
import MapKit
class customPin: NSObject, MKAnnotation {
    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
    var title: String?
    var subtitle: String?

    init(pinTitle:String, pinSubTitle:String, location:CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
        self.title = pinTitle
        self.subtitle = pinSubTitle
        self.coordinate = location
    }
}
class MainViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate,  UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource  {
    @IBOutlet weak var mapview: MKMapView!
 var tableView: UITableView = UITableView()

    var pipCan = [Int: pipiCanDBList]()
    let cellReuseIdentifier = "pipCans"
   override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
         pipiCanList()
         locationMap()
         }
     override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        tableView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 450, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height)
        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        self.view.addSubview(tableView)
    }
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return pipCan.count
    }
 //HERE IS THE PROBLEM

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
     let cell:UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)

     print("test 123")
        // configure cell
      //  let point = pipCan[indexPath.row].
        cell.textLabel?.text = pipCan[indexPath.row]?.ParkName
       // cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "(\(point.coordinate.latitude), \(point.coordinate.longitude))"

        return cell
    }
     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return "Section \(section )"
    }
 func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

   //get the json  information
    func pipiCanList(){

        let url = "http://blueXXXX.lk/Apps/pipiCan/Api/xxxx.php";
        let urlObj = URL(string:url);

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlObj!) {(data, response, error) in
            do{
                let pipiCans = try JSONDecoder().decode([pipiCanDBList].self, from: data!)

                for pipiCan in pipiCans{

                    let Latitude = (pipiCan.ParkLatitude! as NSString).doubleValue
                    let Longitude = (pipiCan.ParkLongitude! as NSString).doubleValue
                    let  location = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: Latitude, longitude: Longitude)

                   DispatchQueue.main.async  {
                        let pin = customPin(pinTitle: pipiCan.ParkName!, pinSubTitle: pipiCan.Area!, location:  location)
                        self.mapview.addAnnotation(pin)
                    }

                }

            } catch{

                print ("Error - cannot get list")

            }

            }.resume()
         }
func locationMap(){

        let latitude1 = 41.3825
        let longitude1 = 2.17694

        let location = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude1  , longitude:longitude1 )
        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: location, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.05, longitudeDelta: 0.05))

        self.mapview.setRegion(region, animated: true)
        self.mapview.delegate = self
    }
 }
```

[image]

Comment: Where is your `pipCan` mutated? I mean, where do you modify this?

Comment: Hi nayem I have the following on a different page
struct pipiCanDBList: Codable {
    let ParkName: String?
    let Area: String?
    let ParkLongitude: String?
    let ParkLatitude: String?
    
}

Comment: I didn't ask you about the structure of your model object. See, you have returned `pipCan.count` from the data source method of table view. But you have only initialized `pipCan` with an empty object and never added more objects to it. So `pipCan.count` always returns **0**. That's why your table view has no row to display.

Comment: Thanks Nayem.
Please can you let me now how I can in intialize the pipCan wont to include the empty object?

Comment: Set `pipiCans ` to `self. pipiCan ` after `try JSONDecoder()~~~`  and 'self.tableView.reloadData()'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a couple of thing in `pipiCanList`

```
self.pipCan = pipiCans
self.tableView.reloadData()
```

So your method will look like

```
func pipiCanList() {

    let url = "http://blueXXXX.lk/Apps/pipiCan/Api/xxxx.php";
    let urlObj = URL(string:url);

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlObj!) {(data, response, error) in
        do {
            let pipiCans = try JSONDecoder().decode([pipiCanDBList].self, from: data!)

            for pipiCan in pipiCans{

                let Latitude = (pipiCan.ParkLatitude! as NSString).doubleValue
                let Longitude = (pipiCan.ParkLongitude! as NSString).doubleValue
                let  location = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: Latitude, longitude: Longitude)

                DispatchQueue.main.async  {
                    let pin = customPin(pinTitle: pipiCan.ParkName!, pinSubTitle: pipiCan.Area!, location:  location)
                    self.mapview.addAnnotation(pin)
                }
            }

            self.pipCan = pipiCans
            self.tableView.reloadData()

        } catch {
            print ("Error - cannot get list")
        }
        }.resume()
}
```